# Why is UIDocumentPickerViewController for Dropbox giving me a previous file version?

Tags: ios, ios8, dropbox, uidocumentpickervc

I am using **UIDocumentPickerViewController** to pick a file from Dropbox and get the callback.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url
 {
    // The user selected the document

    [self importURL:url];
 }
```

At the point I get to my importURL call, the url points to the file in tmp\DocumentPickerIncoming\

If I use Xcode  - Devices to download the container, I find that the incoming file is a previous version of the file from the one that I see in the Dropbox app on the same device. So, I have made a change to the (.csv) data file that I am importing, but my app doesn't get that newest file.

This seems to be out of my control from my app's end. Is there some refresh that has to happen? It seems strange that the Dropbox app shows a different newer version of the file compared to what comes in from the Document Provider.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest version of the Dropbox app (3.9). Are you still seeing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Dropbox App Version 3.9 now and I am not experiencing the problem in my current testing.

I'm not sure that this was happening all of the time, but I suggest the answer is upgrading. Also, Dropbox version 3.9.1 mentions fixing "an issue where old versions of modified PDFs were shown".

Another way to answer this is that there does not seem to be a way to request a refresh; Dropbox should be updating the file automatically.